# TransactionManagerException: Transaction is not current for this thread

Tags: neo4j, apache-camel, neo4j-ogm

I am trying load some data from a CSV file into a clean db instance. I did this by creating an ETL process using Apache Camel it reads the input CSV split the file into multiple lines and process each line in parallel using one transaction per line.

class ImportRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

```
private final Importer importer
private final String endpoint

public ImportRouteBuilder(Importer importer, String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint
    this.importer = importer
}

@Override
void configure() throws Exception {
    from(endpoint)
            .unmarshal(buildCsvDataFormat())
            .split(body())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .bean(importer)
}

private static CsvDataFormat buildCsvDataFormat() {
    CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
    csv.skipHeaderRecord = true
    csv
}
```

}

```
@Slf4j
@Service
class CountryCsvImporter implements Importer {
   @Autowired
   private CountryRepository countryRepository

   @Autowired
   private Session session

   @Override
   void process(List record) {
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       try {
          importCountry(record)
          tx.commit()
       }catch (Throwable t) {
          tx.rollback()
     }
     tx.close()
    }
```

I did this because did not wanted to use LOAD CSV cypher or Neo4j import tool while my model is still evolving since it is very handy to use OGM while prototyping. But now I found a wall at the middle of the process OGM generates this **TransactionManagerException**, it looks like it was some threading issue managing transactions.

at com.cartrawler.service.CountryImportSpecification.Should be able to import country csv(CountryImportSpecification.groovy:9)
Caused by: ***org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionManagerException: Transaction is not current for this thread***
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.rollback(DefaultTransactionManager.java:78)
at org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.rollback(AbstractTransaction.java:65)
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.transaction.EmbeddedTransaction.rollback(EmbeddedTransaction.java:60)
at com.cartrawler.service.CountryCsvImporter.process(CountryCsvImporter.groovy:28)

Thank you, kindly
  Luis Oscar

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your question twice, just to make it easier to read, but you keep changing it back. If you want to fix it yourself, please learn [how to indent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code and stacktraces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off parallel processing as transaction is single thread only.

Comment: Hi Claus, I was able to get the import working in parallel when moved to spring data and by having importer running from a seda queue.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Does this mean concurrent access to the database is impossible? How to turn off parallel processing?